# Access files through linux symlink

Tags: linux, symlink

In the toy example below, I have a folder structure: `toy/subdir/toy.txt`. Then I created a symlink using command:

```
ln -s toy/ ln_dir/toy_link
```

I was expecting to access `subdir` or `subdir/toy.txt` directly from `ln_dir/toy_link`, but when I did

```
less ln_dir/toy_link/subdir/toy.txt
```

I got error

> ln_dir/toy_link/subdir/toy.txt: No such file or directory

My question is, what is the proper way to access files from a symlink? Thanks

[image: directory stucure]

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Symlinks are interpreted relative to the directory that contains them. So It should be `ln -s ../toy/ ln_dir/toy_link` so it goes up a level.